# Ng-src not working for locally stored image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I'm trying something in angularjs. This is the controller I made:

```
function ImagesController($scope){
    $scope.count = 0;
    $scope.imags = [
        {
            image1: 'images/levels/level1/sky.jpg',
            image2: 'images/levels/level1/rain.jpg',
            image3: 'images/levels/level1/sky.jpg'
        },
        {
            image1: 'images/levels/level2/x.jpg',
            image2: 'images/levels/level2/y.jpg',
            image3: 'images/levels/level2/z.jpg'
        }
    ];
  }
```

And this is the HTML linking to this controller:

```
<div ng-controller="ImagesController">
      Random Writing
        <img ng-src="$scope.imags[0].image1">
 </div>
```

I don't know why the image that I'm trying to display is not working. I have added ng-app to the  tag already so that can't be the issue.

Comment: should be ng-src="imags[0].image1"

Comment: @user3757732 take a look at my answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I belive you should write

```
   <img ng-src="{{imags[0].image1}}>
```

Link to the [directives documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSrc)

Comment: Thanks! I changed a couple of things and added the {{}}. Now, the image is loading!