# ng-src for local images

Tags: angularjs, image

I have an AngularJS project and I am trying to show an image from local folder. 
My folder hierarchy is like this:

```
--app(folder)
-----controllers(folder)
-----services(folder)
-----views(folder)
--------images(folder)
-----------image1.jpg
-----------image2.jpg
-----------image3.jpg
--------persons.html
--------departments.html
--index.html
```

I have in image address in `personsController.js`:

```
$scope.fooImageAddress='images/image1.jpg';
```

and in `person.html`:

```
<img ng-src="{{ fooImageAddress}}" alt="here should be an image"/>
```

And nothing shows, just `alt` message if `img`. 
What can I do?

I've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24858200/ng-src-not-working-for-locally-stored-image) question, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32747964/inangularjs-ng-src-for-img-doesnt-show-for-local-files) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34857523/ng-src-not-working-for-local-url-in-public-folder), and tried suggestions, nevertheless there is no result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must change your address, relative to your index.html file

So I suppose `app/views/images/image1.jpg`

Comment: Upvoted! You are right! Thanks! I will accept in 2 minutes:).

Answer (score 0):

it is look like wrong path from a controller the path is different:

```
$scope.fooImageAddress='../views/images/image1.jpg';
```

if is was from person page , you was right.

why are you using "ng-src" and not src if is only one image but use like that

```
<img ng-src="{{'images/'+imageName+'.jpg'}}" alt="here should be an image"/>

$scope.imageName = image1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this one, "fooImageAddress" is a parameters.

```
 <img src= "assets/images/{{fooImageAddress}}" />
```